# log4net closed appender error with config in code

Tags: log4net, appender

I got in trouble with my l4n configuration. 
Working on a big project, I try to configure my logger(s) via code. 
So this is my only app.config-content:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="NESSEEServerCoreLogger">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

And the following is written in the Code, in this case in the Ctor of one class: 
(Only change: The m_RFA member is a class member in productive code)

```
log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter lrf = new log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter();
lrf.LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Info;
lrf.LevelMax = log4net.Core.Level.Fatal;

//create and configure rolling file appender
log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender m_Rfa = new log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender();
m_Rfa.Name = "NESSEEServerCore_RFA";
m_Rfa.ImmediateFlush = true;
m_Rfa.AppendToFile = true;
m_Rfa.File = @"C:\Temp\NESSEEServerCore_Log.txt";
m_Rfa.MaxFileSize = 52428800;  // 50 MiB
m_Rfa.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
m_Rfa.StaticLogFileName = true;
m_Rfa.RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;

var layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout()
{
    ConversionPattern = "[%utcdate{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff}] %level\t%type{1}->%method:%line : %message %newline"
};

layout.ActivateOptions();
m_Rfa.Layout = layout;
m_Rfa.AddFilter(lrf);
m_Rfa.AddFilter(new log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter());
m_Rfa.ActivateOptions();
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(m_Rfa);
```

This works fine so far. 
The only problem is: 
Sometimes, when an exception occures in the application (running as an windows service, I integrated a button to provoke an exception), the logger stopps writing to the file. 
I already turned on internal debugging on l4n. This gives me the following output:

```
7/31/2013 1:42:30 PM: log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Attempted to append to closed appender named [NESSEEServerCore_RFA].
7/31/2013 1:42:30 PM: log4net:ERROR [FileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Attempted to append to closed appender named [].
```

The second file Appender seems to be the one for internal debugging itself. 
After 1:42:30, there are no log entries any more.

What do I have to do to fix this problem? 
Do I have to reinitialize the logger completely?

Comment: Do you know why the appender is being closed?  Is the m_Rfa variable static in your code?

Comment: No, I have no idea. m_Rfa is a global, but non-static variable. 
I now solved itnow using a separate method to re-initialize the logger in case of an uncaught exception. At least, it works, even if I am sure there must be a more easy solution...